# c# scrolling text above the form elements

Tags: c#, winforms, scroll, overlay

I create a scrolling text with DrawString.
It works, but the text remains under the form elements. I would like the text to pass over.
The code:

```
    int x = 0;
    string texto = "prova prova";
    int tam = 15;

    private void timer_Tick_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
                 Graphics gra = this.CreateGraphics();
        gra.CompositingQuality = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.CompositingQuality.HighQuality;
        gra.DrawString(texto, new Font("Times New Roman", tam), new SolidBrush(Color.CornflowerBlue),x, 70);
        gra.Dispose();

            x += 6;

        if (x >= this.Width)
            x = texto.Length * tam * -1;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is by design, a Graphics object can only paint to the area it was created for.

If you want the text to appear in front of all other elements on the Form, you have to create a custom control which does the drawing.

Add an instance of this control to the Form and use the BringToFront method to position it on top of each other contained elements in the Form.